# Como fazer com que foreach jquery nao repita os dados quando abro janela model?

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma janela `modal` que quando abro carrega-me os dados que preciso ter através de um `foreach` jquery.  Só que se fechar a `modal` e voltar a abrir, repetem-se todos os dados que vem do `foreach`. Como posso fazer para evitar isso?

**jquery**

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-add-agent-proximo", function(e) {
  if($('#add_agent').is(':checked')){ 
    $('#modal-add-agent').modal('hide'); 

    var id_agente_pai = <?= Auth::user()->id ?>

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://artslots.net/admin/list_agent",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        data: { id_agente_pai : 'id_agente_pai'},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function( data ) {
        $.each(data.parents, function( key, parents ) {
            $('#parent').append('<option value="'+parents.id+'"><span>ID('+parents.id+') </span>'+parents.username+'</option>');
        });
        $.each(data.currencies, function( key, currencies ) {
            $('#currency').append('<option value="'+currencies.id+'">'+currencies.code+'</option>');
        });
        $.each(data.funcoes, function( key, funcoes ) {
            $('#funcoes').append('<option value="'+funcoes.id+'">'+funcoes.nome+'</option>');
        });

    }).fail(function(data) {
        toastr.error('Ocorreu um erro!');
    });

    $('#modal-add-agent-modal').modal('show');

  }else if($('#add_jogador').is(':checked')){ 
    $('#modal-add-agent').modal('hide'); 

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://artslots.net/admin/list_agent",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        data: { id_agente_pai : 'id_agente_pai'},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function( data ) {
        $.each(data.parents, function( key, parents ) {
            $('#parent_jogador').append('<option value="'+parents.id+'"><span>ID('+parents.id+') </span>'+parents.username+'</option>');
        });

    }).fail(function(data) {
        toastr.error('Ocorreu um erro!');
    });

    $('#modal-add-jogador-modal').modal('show');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu pode limpar os dados no evento que é acionado quando a modal é fechada, por exemplo:

```
$('#modal-add-agent').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        ...
 });
```

Sempre que tu fechar a modal `$('#modal-add-agent').modal('hide');` esse evento vai ser acionado, ai tu pode usar o [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) do jquery, que remove todos os nós filhos do elemento que tu quiser.

ex:

```
$('#parent').empty();
```

Comment: Obrigado era mesmo isso funcionou certinho